# SQL Server: Benefit of a non-persisted computed column vs views

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, persistent

I can understand the benefits of a `persisted` computed column: calculations which will always yield the same results might as well be cached on insert/update to save time and effort later.

Is there a special benefit of a non-persistent calculated column? Isn’t that the same as saving a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a special benefit of a non-persistent calculated column?

vs. a persisted calculated column it saves on storage and can still be indexed.
vs. a view it saves you from having a separate object to manage.

But neither kind of calculated columns are used extensively.

David

Comment: Can you not index a calculation without a computed column?

Comment: Ah, it seems that SQL Server doesn’t support Indexes on Expressions. In this case, a computed column does the job. See http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/function_based_indexes. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes.  SQL Server has no function-based indexes, but has indexes on non-persisted computed columns, and indexed views.